# Kotlin, generic operation on Number

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have the following

```
abstract interface Vec2t<T : Number> {    
    var x: T
    var y: T
}
```

`data class Vec2(override var x: Float, override var y: Float) : Vec2t<Float>`

and I have an interface where I define several operations, e.g:

```
interface fun_vector2_common {

    fun abs(res: Vec2, a: Vec2): Vec2 {
        res.x = glm.abs(a.x)
        res.y = glm.abs(a.y)
        return res
    }
}
```

Is it possible to implement, let's say `abs`, by using generics?

```
interface fun_vector2_common<T : Number> {

    fun abs(res: Vec2t<T>, a: Vec2t<T>): Vec2t<T> {
        res.x = glm.abs(a.x)  // error
        res.y = glm.abs(a.y)  // error
        return res
    }
}
```

And then the corresponding `glm.abs()` based on the type will be called?

The above code fails because it expects, obviously, a `glm.abs(n: Number)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement floor modulo for every Number type in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38052008/how-to-implement-floor-modulo-for-every-number-type-in-kotlin)

Comment: Various solutions have been proposed. There's a request for [structural types](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-218) to be added to Kotlin, but it doesn't appear to have traction. Fairly recently a KEEP for [type classes](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/pull/87) was created. There's also an extensive discussion on [extension types](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/extension-types-for-kotlin/1390/14), which are basically type classes but arising as an expansion of extension functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately [there's no clean way to have generic `abs` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777139/generic-method-absolute-value-java). You can work it around with the following `abs` definition:

```
object glm {
    fun <T : Number> abs(x: T): T {
        val absoluteValue: Number = when (x) {
            is Double -> Math.abs(x)
            is Int -> Math.abs(x)
            is Float -> Math.abs(x)
            is BigDecimal -> x.abs()
            is BigInteger -> x.abs()
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("unsupported type ${x.javaClass}")
        }
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return absoluteValue as T
    }
}
```

Which would make it possible to use in your context:

```
fun abs(res: Vec2, a: Vec2): Vec2 {
    res.x = glm.abs(a.x)
    ...
}
```

Comment: The when statement only works at runtime, right? I suppose there is no way to make it static...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar design requirement for a similar use case, and the structure I ended up with was something like this:

```kotlin
class Vec2<T : Number>(
    val x: T,
    val y: T,
    private val valueAdapter: ValueAdapter<T>
) {
    fun length(): T = valueAdapter.sqrt(
        valueAdapter.add(
            valueAdapter.multiply(x, x),
            valueAdapter.multiply(y, y)
        )
    )

    companion object {
        fun ofDouble(x: Float, y: Float): Vec2t<Float> =
            Vec2(x, y, ValueAdapter.forFloat)

        fun ofDouble(x: Double, y: Double): Vec2t<Double> =
            Vec2(x, y, ValueAdapter.forDouble)
    }
}

// There's probably a better name for this interface. `Field`?
interface ValueAdapter<T: Number> {
    fun add(x: T, y: T): T
    fun multiply(x: T, y: T): T
    fun sqrt(x: T): T

    companion object {
        val forFloat: ValueAdapter<Float> = object : ValueAdapter<Float> {
            override fun add(x: Float, y: Float) = x + y
            override fun multiply(x: Float, y: Float) = x * y
            override fun sqrt(x: Float) = sqrt(x)
        }

        val forDouble: ValueAdapter<Double> = object : ValueAdapter<Double> {
            override fun add(x: Double, y: Double) = x + y
            override fun multiply(x: Double, y: Double) = x * y
            override fun sqrt(x: Double) = sqrt(x)
        }
    }
}
```

With this sort of layout, someone who has their own type they want to slot in can just implement their own value adapter for their custom type.

And in theory, you don't really need to restrict it to `Number`.

Also FWIW, I eventually ended up abandoning this structure, not because it doesn't work for the use case, but because I came across more use cases, for example, sometimes the square root of a `Double` returned a `Complex`. So I eventually wound up having a single set of operations allowing `Any`.

Answer (score 0):

Played with this a bit and I found a much faster solution to calculate mode, didn't try for the other two:

```
fun <T : Number> List<T>.mode(): T {
    return this.groupBy { it }.maxBy { it.value.size }.key
}
```