# Kotlin generic function

Tags: generics, kotlin

I wrote a `Complex` generics class to represent a complex number and want to be able to store the internal numbers as the type user passed in. And a `add_complex()` function to add two complex numbers.

```
class Complex<T: Number>(val real:T, val imagine:T)

fun<T:Number> add_complex(l:Complex<T>, r:Complex<T>): Complex<T>
{
    return Complex(l.real+r.real, l.imagine+r.imagine)
}

fun main()
{
    var x=Complex<Int>(2,3)
    var y=Complex<Int>(4,5)
    var sum=add_complex(x,y)
    print("${sum.real},${sum.imagine}i")
}
```

The compiler is giving a long list of error messages about possible match of `plus` function. But I don't know what's the problem, and the kotlin reference didn't provide much info about generic functions. And I came from C++ and I have a rough understanding of C++ templates. It will be much appreciated if someone can explain the main difference between C++ templates and kotlin generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference with C++ templates is that in C++ the compiler simply substitutes templates types to produce new specialized types, new functions, etc.

So X<int> and X<double> end up being two new classes, while in Kotlin there is only one X class, and in addition in Kotlin at runtime the generic types are erased (ie at runtime Integer and Double simply disappear, they are only needed by the compiler).  Here C++ would simply create a Complex<int> class and use that.

In Kotlin, the problem here is that the addition ends up being an addition operation that needs to know whether it is an addition of longs, of floats, etc.  And since the generic types are erased, and there is only one Complex class, it would need to handle all possibilities.  So your code would have to be changed to handle each such case.  Or default to a single type like this:

```
class Complex<T: Number>(val real:T, val imagine:T) {
    fun add(o: Complex<T>): Complex<Double> {
        var r = real.toDouble() + o.real.toDouble()
        var i = imagine.toDouble() + o.imagine.toDouble()
        return Complex(r, i)
    }
}
```

or

```
fun<T:Number> add_complex(l:Complex<T>, r:Complex<T>): Complex<Double> {
    return Complex(l.real.toDouble() +r.real.toDouble(), l.imagine.toDouble()+r.imagine.toDouble())
}
```

Comment: Can you demo a little of how to do write this function outside a class scope?

Answer (score 0):

In C++ template code is generated for each specialization and then compiled. Here it works differently. No generation, same code you've written is called for all cases.
There is no clean way to do same in kotlin. Even this code gives an error:

```
val x:Number = 1.0;
val z:Float = 2.0f;

val r = x + z;
```

Number class doesn't define any plus operator function. You need to manually check what type you are dealing with and call plus function operation then. In error message I suppose you received that none of plus() functions fit for your case.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587118/kotlin-generic-operation-on-number) or Google "kotlin generic number function"